# I am not able to understand what is happening

Tags: c, pointers

I found a c program to remove duplicates in string and return the new string .But, I am not figuring out how a pointer returning function got simply printed in main block and how there is desired length of returned string.

```
char *solve(char s[],int n){
    int i=0,index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<i+1;j++){
            if(s[i]==s[j])
            break;
        }
        if(i==j){
            s[index++]=s[i];
        }
    }
    return s;
}
int main() 
{ 
   char str[]= "aabrakadabra"; 
   int n = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]);
   printf(solve(str,n));
}
```

Output: 'abrkd'

please explain!!

Comment: If you have a question about *how the language works*, then Stack Overflow is not the right place for you. Try to follow a tutorial, or ask on a forum such as Reddit or Quora. Stack Overflow is mainly for finding problems in code that you wrote and fixing them. It is not for explaining working code that was written by someone else.

Comment: [The first argument to `printf` is a pointer to `char`.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: In any case, we cannot answer questions like "I can't understand what is happening" because *we don't understand why you don't understand it*.

Comment: The first argument to `printf` is a format spcifier. `printf(solve(str,n));` looks dangerous (but in this case it is actually safe). It should be `printf("%s", solve(str,n));` or `fputs(solve(str,n), stdout);`.

Comment: The length of the array (not the length of the string) is passed as the size to process, so the terminating null-character is also copied as a non-duplicate element.

Comment: This program does nothing as it reads outside the array bounds

Comment: Functions get the string length looking for `0x00` that is present at the end of each string.
So the string buffer must have a size of at least the number of characters + 1.
If this byte is not present all string functions will fail: printf, strcpy, strcmp, etc.

Comment: @0___________, Undefined Behaviour does not mean "does nothing" - it means "whatever it does is out of the hands of the C language". Also, please show where array bounds are exceeded.

Comment: @mlp - nothing predictable. Is invalid so in the fact it does nothing even if does something.